# how to handle buttons on a page?

Tags: php, html

I am newbie in php.I don't know how to handle buttons on a page.
I have 4 button: insert,update,del,select( view all record of table on database). I want  update,del,select button go to 3 other pages. Insert button handle mainpage.
Please give me an advice.

Comment: Have a quick referance [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798877/run-a-php-function-upon-button-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798877/run-a-php-function-upon-button-click)

Comment: if only redirect, try use link instead buttons.
Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button for example.

Comment: Sorry. but all 4 buttons have same tag<form>. And i cna't use ajax/Jquery here due to some reasons.

Comment: create different forms for 4 buttons as submit buttons with action value for each as url to the page required.on clicking the form will be submitted(redirected) to that page

Comment: Do you have to use buttons? Why can't u use text instead and use a href?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps

```
<form action="your normal url">
  <input type="submit" name="select" value="select"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="update"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" formaction="your other page url">
</form>
```

Wanna learn about it click [formaction](http://w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp)