# How can I change the characteristics of css?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a CSS which looks like in my

```
style.css
~~~~~~~
.spanish{
display : initial;
}

.english{
display : initial;
}
```

and I have a HTML like:

```
<HTML>
<head>
    <link rel=StyleSheet type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="codecss.php" value = spanish>
<input type="button" onclick="codecss.php" value = english>
<input type="button" onclick="codecss.php" value = both>

<table>
<tr class= "spanish"><td> This is spanish text </td></tr>
<tr class = "english"><td> This is english text </td></tr>
<table>
</body>
<HTML>
```

Now I need help with PHP. I want a way when I click on Spanish then my HTML should display only Spanish and if clicked English then only English should be displayed. and both if pressed "both" button.

How can I edit my css from php according to the button pressed in my html???
Please help/

Comment: You cannot use php for this, you need a javascript based logic, since this has to be done on the client side. In javascript you register an onClick handler for the language selector and then change the `display` to visible / not hidden for all elements of the corresponding classes.

Comment: Here's a question about [how to run PHP when you click a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798877/run-a-php-function-upon-button-click). Javascript (or jQuery) are involved, as was previously commented

Answer (score 0):

I just write a basic code snippet, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
$('asd.languageChange').click(function() {
  var language = '.' + $(this).attr('id');
  $('.language').hide();
  $(language).show();
})
```

```css
.spanish {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="english" class="languageChange">English</button>
<button id="spanish" class="languageChange">Spanish</button>

<table>
<tr class="spanish language"><td> This is spanish text </td></tr>
<tr class="english language"><td> This is english text </td></tr>
<table>
```

Another option. You can also do it using `Javascript`.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target.matches(".languageChange")) {
   var hideAllLanguages = document.getElementsByClassName("language");
   for(var i = 0; i < hideAllLanguages.length; i++){
     hideAllLanguages[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   
   var showRequiredLanguage = document.getElementsByClassName(e.target.id);
   for(var i = 0; i < showRequiredLanguage.length; i++){
     showRequiredLanguage[i].style.display = "block";
   }
  }
});
```

```css
.spanish {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="english" class="languageChange">English</button>
<button id="spanish" class="languageChange">Spanish</button>

<table>
<tr class="spanish language"><td> This is spanish text </td></tr>
<tr class="english language"><td> This is english text </td></tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Can you describe those things in plain JavaScript. I am having hard time to understand that. Especially that looks like PHP to me when I see $. But as long as I can change my .English to display:none in all of my html files I would be fine. By the way I have 100 html files which all looks same, it's a book. So I want to implement for whole book when button is pressed. Thanks

Comment: @RochakKunwar i also added Javascript example in above snippet. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks